# Resizing image loaded from Javascript Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, arrays, image-resizing

Using javascript array to load random images in div
Javascript code working great
but loaded image are showing in their actual size even after using css to div
and overlapping each other
is there any way to resize image in javascript 
or any other way to fit them in specific sized div

here is javascript i used directly in html file :

```
<div class="glbx-small">

       <script>    
           var arrayImg = new Array();
           arrayImg[0] = "a1.jpg";
           arrayImg[1] = "a2.jpg";


            getRandomImage(arrayImg, "");

          function getRandomImage(imgAr, path) {
            path = path || 'images/'; // default path here
            var num = Math.floor( Math.random() * imgAr.length );
            var img = imgAr[ num ];
            var imgStr = '<img src="' + path + img + '" alt = "">';
            document.write(imgStr); document.close();
}

         </script>

</div>
```

css used for glbx-small :

```
.glbx-small {
    align-content: center;
    width: 18%;
    height: 6vw;
    border: thin solid #B0B0B0 1px;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```
.glbx-small img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
.glbx-small img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```